# Stripe Commerce Plugin - Checkout Payment Form Type (capture address)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-commerce-stripe

I am using this checkout option in my commerce site with the Stripe Commerce Plugin:

paymentFormType: 'checkout',

However it only captures the clients Postcode - is there an easy way to capture Billng Address also (my client wants it for invoice even though payments are going through only with postcode). Wasnt sure if i needed to pass another parameter or if this is something that needs to be changes in Stripe itself?

Many thanks
Malcolm